# Extract Jar file from web applet

Tags: java, applet

Can i extract jar file from this java based web applet for offline use?
This is the link to the applet:
http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/365/li/squeeze/LZW.html

Comment: There is an easier way. The very page linked to, states in the last paragraph *"If you would like the source code, the .java files are in [lzw.zip](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/365/li/squeeze/lzw.zip)."* So download the source and build it yourself.

Comment: the code is so messy , i couldnt make it work , i tried